# Layout change until file load when using custom font with CSS

Tags: css, layout, fonts

I am using custom font with css in my site. Site looks excelent after 100% load.
But my site's desing and layout is all wrong while site loading.

How can i keep layout while custom fonts loading.?

Thanks

Edit :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reset.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/nivo-slider.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/layout.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/custom-font.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/default/default.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//    $(window).load(function() {
//        $('#slideShow').nivoSlider();
//    });

    $(window).load(function() {
    $('#slideShow').nivoSlider({
        startSlide:1, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
        slideshowEnd: function(){$('#slideShow').data('nivo:vars').stop = true;} 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example link so we can see what is going on?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Original post was edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do that is to import your css file in your html header. like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link .... /> //css style
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

This way the page will first load the css and after the design and js or whatever you have.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it is already done. <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/custom-font.css">